# PHP file_get_contents from a page which uses jQuery innerHTML

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have two files, one named **location.php** which is sourced here: http://jsfiddle.net/g25y68kb/ which displays locations from Google Map's API using innerHTML which I intend to separate by an asterisk (*).

I am trying to put the results from this page in to a PHP Array, here is what I have tried:

```
<?php
$url = "location.php";
$lines = file_get_contents($url);
print_r ( explode( '*', $lines ) );
?>
```

This returns:

```
Array( [0] => )
```

However, when removing explode and just using `print_r($lines);` it returns correctly as it does in the JSFiddle above like:

`Emirates Stadium, Hornsey Road, London, United Kingdom*Stadium Residential, London, United Kingdom*stadium near London, United Kingdom*Olympic Stadium, London, United Kingdom*Fulham Taxis/Stadium Car Minicab Services, Fulham Road, London, United Kingdom*`

Although, when I view the source, obviously I can only see the JavaScript and not the location values from innerHTML, so I'm guessing this is the problem?

Is there any work around or better way to do this?

Comment: That's dynamic content added by javascript, it's not part of the original source, which is what PHP is getting.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification of what I guessed towards the end of my question, I am asking if there is any other possible method to do what I'm trying?

Comment: There is, you can use a headless browser

Answer (score 1):

All the JS code is interpreted in the browser context, in memory of the client machine. This is the reason your PHP code with context in web server can't reach this data.

You can set an array with the results and pass to your php script via ajax like this:

```
            var resultList = [];
            for (var i = 0, prediction; prediction = predictions[i]; i++) {
                results.innerHTML += prediction.description + '*';
                resultList.push(prediction.description);
            }

            $.post( "test.php", { 'results': resultList} );
```

In test.php you can eval var `$_POST['results']` to obtain the json list.

Or maybe you can do like sugested by @adeneo, with an automation framework with headless browser like [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/)